# Inserting a array of php values into a select options via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select elements, and each select form is either a block type or a block content. So in total i have around 10 select elements, 5 of which are block type and 5 are block content. The select options of block content will be determined by what the user select in block type.
I have 3 arrays (property, blogs, message), which have the values needed for block content.

So what i need to do is-
check what the user has selected for block type- which i have done.
Populate the block content with the relevant values- this is where i am having problems.

Here is my javascript code so far

```
$(".blockTypeWrapper .blockType").change(function() {
var currentBlock = $(this).val();
var blockContent = $(this).parent().siblings('.blockContentWrapper .blockContent');

if (currentBlock == '1') {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var propertyData = <?php echo $properties; ?>;
    $.each(propertyData, function() {
        options.append(new Option(option.text, option.value));
    });
};
if (currentBlock == '2') {
    $(this).siblings(".blockContent").addClass("active");  
};
if (currentBlock == '3') {
    $(this).siblings(".blockContent").addClass("active");  
};
```

});

Ignore the currentBlock == '2' and 3 code, i am just trying to get it working for one first.

If there are any other easier way of achieving this then i'm all ears.
EDIT

```
echo $this->Form->input('main_block_type',  
    array(
      'options' => array(
        1 => 'Property',
        2 => 'Blogs',
        3 => 'Message'
      ), 
      'label' => 'Main Block Type', 
      'empty' => 'Please Select',
      'class' => 'blockType',
      'div' => array(
        'class' => 'blockTypeWrapper'
      )
    )
  );

echo $this->Form->input('main_block',  
    array(
      'options' => $blogs, 
      'label' => 'Main Block Content', 
      'empty' => 'Please Select',
      'class' => 'blockContent',
      'div' => array(
        'class' => 'blockContentWrapper'
      )
    )
  );
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post some html corresponding to this chunk of code? are you getting exceptions in the console? also, I'm not sure if "new Option()" syntax is supported in newer browsers... you might want to check on that.

Comment: Hi, i have added the corresponding code, although its in cakephp not HTML. With regards to new option(), its something i came across while researching and i was just trying it out. I get a error which states string to array conversion failed. I believe that is due to "var propertyData = <?php echo $properties;?> bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access Array with echo. You need to access with:

`<?php echo json_encode($properties); ?>;`

try below code:

```
if (currentBlock == '1') {
            var propertyData = <?php echo json_encode($properties); ?>;

             $(".blockContent").empty();  // You can remove all the options by using empty() function.

            $.each(propertyData, function (i, item) {
                $('.blockContent').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item.value,
                    text: item.text
                }));
            });
        }
```

PHP Array of properties should be like this:

```
$properties = array(
    'item1' => array('text' => 'item1 text', 'value' => 'item 1 value'),
    'item2' => array('text' => 'item2 text', 'value' => 'item 2 value'),
    'item3' => array('text' => 'item3 text', 'value' => 'item 3 value')
);
```

Comment: Great it seems to be working, just a slight issue. The dropdown list appear to have items in it but the values arent showing. So the size of the list changes, however all i see is empty list.  Also i will need to replace the the dropdown list rather than append. So do i need to delete the current value of option and then add new values to it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please note `$(".blockContent").empty();` , is used to remove all options from select. and also check `$properties` array. The 'value' key  is changed.

Comment: Perfect all works fine. Just had to change few bits of the code to accommodate my array structure.Thanks!